# Ephemeral containers in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, sidecar

I create a standard nginx pod and I want to run a sidecar container, but it's not working for me in Kubernetes 1.18 - 1.20.

```
# kubectl alpha debug nginx --image=busybox --target=nginx
Defaulting debug container name to debugger-6wlb5.

# kubectl attach nginx -c debugger-6wlb5
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
error: unable to upgrade connection: container debugger-6wlb5 not found in pod nginx_default
```

I have gates feature enabled in apiserver, scheduler & controller-manager. Describe on pod doesn't show errors or something:

```
Mounts:
    /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-4jhz2 (ro)
Ephemeral Containers:
  debugger-6wlb5:
    Image:        busybox
    Port:         <none>
    Host Port:    <none>
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:       <none>
Conditions:
  Type              Status
```

What do I miss here?

Answer (score 3):

#### Background

Unfortunately this is still `alfa feature` and it's not suitable for production. As stated in [Ephemeral Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/ephemeral-containers/) documentation.

> This page provides an overview of ephemeral containers: a special type of container that runs temporarily in an existing Pod to accomplish user-initiated actions such as troubleshooting. You use ephemeral containers to inspect services rather than to build applications.

> **Warning:** Ephemeral containers are in early alpha state and are not suitable for production clusters.

#### Tests

I have tested this on `Kubeadm` with Kubernetes 1.19. [Feature Gates](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/feature-gates/) flag was set in config files like `apiserver`, `scheduler` and `controller-manager` - `--feature-gates=EphemeralContainers=true`. Also `kubelet` was modified.
As this is `alpha` it needs specific steps to make it work.

**Option 1**

This method is described in [Debug Running Pods - Debugging with an ephemeral debug container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container).

```
$ kubectl run ephemeral-demo --image=k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1 --restart=Never
pod/ephemeral-demo created
$ kubectl alpha debug -it ephemeral-demo --image=busybox --target=ephemeral-demo
Defaulting debug container name to debugger-hnr2w.
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ # ps aux
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 /pause
    7 root      0:00 sh
   12 root      0:00 ps aux
/ # Now, you are in the debugger-hnr2w container which is in the same pod as container ephemeral-demo
/ # exit
$
```

***Describe pod***

```
Containers:
  ephemeral-demo:
    Container ID:   docker://e24cf29efdab9fbf8180ec6c8a9539cdfbdfc490b3b4a4d5dd02d419887c8486
    Image:          k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.1
    ...
Ephemeral Containers:
  debugger-hnr2w:
    Container ID:   docker://649d020e92eedbe03d281fb2368f33ceec176eaaa340fb52af5bf59fc269c701
    Image:          busybox
    ...
```

In example above, `attach` was made by using `-i` flag. It's stated in [Copying a Pod while adding a new container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#copying-a-pod-while-adding-a-new-container).

> The -i flag causes kubectl debug to attach to the new container by default. You can prevent this by specifying --attach=false.

**Side Note**

There second part of quotation is that `If your session becomes disconnected you can reattach using kubectl attach.` however it applies to another method, not `Ephemeral Containers`.

**Option 2**

This option and all prerequisite are described in [Ephemeral Containers — the future of Kubernetes workload debugging](https://medium.com/01001101/ephemeral-containers-the-future-of-kubernetes-workload-debugging-c5b7ded3019f) article. Instead of `Deployment` I have used `nginx` pod.

`$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx`.

Next you have to create `.json` file with below configuration. Please change `metadata.name` to your pod name.

```
{
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "kind": "EphemeralContainers",
    "metadata": {
            "name": "nginx"
    },
    "ephemeralContainers": [{
        "command": [
            "sh"
        ],
        "image": "busybox:latest",
        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent",
        "name": "debugger",
        "stdin": true,
        "tty": true,
        "terminationMessagePolicy": "File"
    }]
}
```

**IMPORTANT**

You have to apply it using `kubectl replace --raw`

```
$ kubectl replace --raw /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/<podName>/ephemeralcontainers -f <jsonFileName>.json
```

Otherwise, you will get error:

```
kubectl apply -f debug.json 
error: unable to recognize "debug.json": no matches for kind "EphemeralContainers" in version "v1"
```

After applying proper command:

```
$ kubectl replace --raw /api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/nginx/ephemeralcontainers -f debug.json
{"kind":"EphemeralContainers","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{"name":"nginx","namespace":"default","selfLink":"/api/v1/namespaces/default/pods/nginx/ephemeralcontainers","uid":"...}
```

Use `kubectl describe <podname>` to verify if `EphemeralContainer` was created.

```
$ kubectl describe po | grep 'Container ID' -B 2
Containers:
  nginx:
    Container ID:   docker://a410b326cdc3b95abb2edff8cdb4d7edca9498ba44b54ca6a448967596391813
--
Ephemeral Containers:
  debugger:
    Container ID:  docker://a1357c0daed0ad5664b8c838183a3eb0716339020e829077c14e7438fa5e1cf5
```

Using this method you will be able to use `kubectl attach`

```
$ kubectl attach -it nginx -c debugger
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
/ #
```

#### Conclusion

`Ephemeral Container` is a special type of container that runs temporarily in an existing Pod to accomplish user-initiated actions such as troubleshooting. One you will terminate session, you will not be able to connect again.

You will get error:

```
$ kubectl attach -it nginx -c debugger
If you don't see a command prompt, try pressing enter.
error: unable to upgrade connection: container debugger not found in pod nginx_default
```

It might be changed in the future but based on my tests, you can connect to this container only once.

Comment: Hi, PjoterS! Thanks. Is there another way to add a sidecar to a RUNNING pod?

Comment: If pod is running, you can only use ephemeral sidecar. If you would have pod with another container as sidecar, you can `copy` existing one and add new container as sidecar. It's described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#copying-a-pod-while-adding-a-new-container). Another option would be use some `Istio` features - [Sidecar Injection](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/additional-setup/sidecar-injection/)